# Are there any situations where spacetime expansion causes an increase in mass?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, mass, astrophysics, space-expansion

Is there any situation where in an accelerating expanding universe (like our own one) there can be an increase in mass in any given system (e.g. a galaxy or a cosmic-scale structure)? Can the Hubble flow somehow cause an increase of mass of certain systems in some situations?

Answer (score 0):

No, mass is invariant. The Hubble flow just increases the distance between masses unless these are gravitationally bound like e.g. the stars within galaxies.

Comment: Not considering FRW geometry, is mass invariant in a generic expanding universe?

Comment: Mass doesn't care about expansion, mass is invariant. What matters is mass density which goes with 1/a³.

Comment: 1/a³ relation is a feature of FRW geometry. Mass doesn't care about expansion is a misleading statement if we consider a generic expansion

Comment: Why do you think that mass isn't invariant in an expanding universe?